# Launch Screen Not Resizing For Landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

For my LaunchScreen file on iPad, I simply have a UIImageView.  I have constraints set to 20 for the top, and 0 for sides and bottom.  For width and height I have >=768 set.  It was my thinking that this would keep the Image Stretched out to all edges (except for top where it would be 20 away) no matter the rotation.  Here is portrait, as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

And here is Landscape

[image]

Here is how I have it set up, I keep telling it 0 on leading and trailing, but it keeps going back to -20.

[image]

Comment: Don't set width and height if you are setting top, bottom, leading and trailing. You could set top, trailing, width and height. Also check that you UIImageView content mode is set correctly - fill or aspect fill for example

Comment: @Paulw11 Scale To Fill is selected.  I'm not checking the width or height in PIN.  I started over from scratch and got close, but no matter what I do, it is setting -20 as leading and trailing space.  Will add screenshot of that in OP.

Comment: You are seeing -20 because "constrain to margins" is selected

Comment: Also have you double checked your project settings to confirm that you are using the launch storyboard and not a launch image

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, it is using the storyboard and not image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly set size class in case if you have iPad Application set for landscape and portrait mode Regular Height and Regular width as in this image

[image: Size class for iPad Application]

Then set constraints like this

[image: Constraints for launch image]

Comment: sadly the images no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

[make sure upside Down is unchecked  in General settings on your project target or your first xib will display in portrait mode on launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBeDw.png)

[image: deployment info]